# Change date-picker text color in spinner mode in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-datepicker

I have tried using custom style but it is not working , its default color is greyish and I want it to be white colored, can anyone help me out? TIA

```
XML

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/user_dob"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    style="@style/MyDatePickerStyle"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"/>

styles   
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker" tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
    <item name="android:minDate">01/01/1970</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use:

```
<DatePicker
   android:theme="@style/MyDatePicker"
   ..>
```

with:

```
<style name="MyDatePicker" >
    <!-- Text color -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/....</item>
    <!-- Divider color -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/...</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Idk why but it's not working for me

Comment: I tried it out, it worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to use android:theme="@style/MyDatePicker" not style="@style/MyDatePicker"